# How do you inherit types in PostgreSQL?

Tags: oracle, postgresql

Can you inherit TYPES, from other TYPES, for example:

```
CREATE TYPE "uniDB"."student" UNDER "uniDB"."person";
```

The TYPE of "person" is already created. This syntax is in Oracle Database for relational objects.

Comment: Por favor traduce la pregunta a español. Gracias

Answer (score 2):

En  PostgreSQL la herencia es para tablas [tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/tutorial-inheritance.html), pero tu puedes simular eso con el siguiente ejemplo:

```
CREATE TYPE person AS  (pname text, pbirthday int );

CREATE TYPE student AS (pperson person, school text, grade text);
```

Comment: de acuerdo, lo voy a traducir al español la respuesta, lo siento